# Pivoting (or reshaping) table in pandas into hierarchical columns

Tags: pandas, pivot, data-manipulation, hierarchical

I have a df such as...

```
     log_ratio   city   type   year
0   2.892095   Detroit  Pos_A  2016
1   2.176814   Detroit  Pos_B  2016
2   3.218273   Detroit  Pos_A  2017
3   2.922206   Detroit  Pos_B  2017
4   2.776701  Columbus  Pos_A  2016
5   2.615424  Columbus  Pos_B  2016
6   2.781899  Columbus  Pos_A  2017
7   2.499343  Columbus  Pos_B  2017
...
```

I want to reshape this table so that the `city` is the index and the `year` and `type` become a hierarchical columns and the `log_ratio` are the values, such as...

```
 mr             2016                2017

           Pos_A    Pos_B      Pos_A   Pos_B 

Detroit  2.892095 2.176814   3.218273 2.922206
Columbus 2.776701 2.615424   2.781899 2.499343
...
```

When I run the command...

```
df3 = df2.pivot(index='mr',columns=['year','type'],values='log_ratio')
```

I get an error...

```
 'Cannot find level year'.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `pd.pivot_table` for this one: `pd.pivot_table(df2, index='city', columns=['year','type'], values='log_ratio')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe). See Question 7 of that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='city', columns=['year','type'], values='log_ratio')
year          2016                2017          
type         Pos_A     Pos_B     Pos_A     Pos_B
city                                            
Columbus  2.776701  2.615424  2.781899  2.499343
Detroit   2.892095  2.176814  3.218273  2.922206
```

For more details, check out this awesome canonical answer: [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)